# How to evaluate DOM element attribute

Tags: javascript, svg

I have an SVG `<circle />` element with a radius of `calc(50% - 16px)`.

In JavaScript, how can this attribute be evaluated to provide the result of `calc`?

https://jsfiddle.net/pgfhhbm8/3/

Comment: Is `calc` even available in SVG? Are elements inside an `<svg>` tag even in the DOM?

Comment: that is a custom expression evaluation. eval() can help but not in this case as 50% & 16px  both have different context

Comment: Call getBoundingClientRect(), divide the width from that by 2 and subtract 16. That's your radius.

Comment: i don't think it's a dublicate. To resolve styles using calc() one can use `getComputedStyle()`. that's what the op asked for... the linked dublicate question does not answer op's question...